# Captura de pantalla de un UITableViewCell desde swift

Tags: ios, swift2, swift, screenshot

Estoy haciendo una app en `swift`, en la que necesito poder hacer una captura de pantalla de una celda concreta de una tabla desde un botón.

Tengo este código:

```
func capturarPantalla(sender: UITableViewCell) {
        let miDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate)
        UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            miDelegate.window?.alpha = 0
            let sound = NSURL (fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sonido", ofType: "mp3")!)
            do {
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: sound)
                print("Reproduciendo sonido")
            } catch let error as NSError {
                print("Hay un error \(error)")
            }
            self.player.prepareToPlay()
            self.player.play()
            }, completion: { finished in
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(sender.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
                sender.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
                let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(PantallaNoticiasTableViewController.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
                miDelegate.window!.alpha = 1
        })
    }

    func image(image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        if error != nil {
            print("KO")
        }
        else {
            print("OK")
        }
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()
    let currentArticleToDisplay:Articulo = self.articles[indexPath.row]
    var btnCaptura: UIButton = UIButton()

    cell.backgroundColor = AppDelegate().getColorFondo()
    cell.sizeToFit()

    btnCaptura = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UIButton
    let tapGestureCa = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(capturarPantalla(_:)))
    tapGestureCa.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    btnCaptura.userInteractionEnabled = true
    btnCaptura.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureCa)
}
```

Pero me da este error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell capturarPantalla:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13895a5b0'
```

Como puedo pasar un parametro en un selector

**EDITADO**

He añadido la solucion de @mhergon pero ahora tengo un error aqui, este error no pasa en todas las celdas, solo en algunas:

```
btnCaptura = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UIButton
```

Imagenes del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**PONE TAG 99 PERO ES PORQUE LO HE CAMBIADO GLOBALMENTE POR SI ACASO. EN LA CELDA DEL TABLE VIEW ESTA TAMBIEN A 99**

Comment: El error que has añadido se debe a que el botón no existe. Utiliza `guard ... else` que para eso está y comprobar que el botón no es `nil`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un lío de conceptos bastante grande.
Para empezar, no tiene sentido añadir un `UITapGestureRecognizer` a un `UIButton` ya que es un botón. Es decir, debes añadir la opción al botón de la siguiente manera:

```
btnCaptura.addTarget(self, action: #selector(capturarPantalla(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

Y cambiando el método de captura a:

```
func capturarPantalla(sender: UIButton) {

    /**
     *  Código...
     */

}
```

Después, tienes que saber en qué celda estás para poder hacer la captura. Aquí tienes dos formas, la primera es buscando la `superview` del `sender` ya que el botón está dentro una `UITableViewCell` etc.
La segunda, y más correcta y segura es la siguiente:

Primero, asigna un `tag` al botón que será el `indexPath` del la celda:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var btnCaptura: UIButton = UIButton()
    btnCaptura.tag = indexPath.row

}
```

De esta manera, en el método de captura, podrás saber qué fila es. Para finalizar y tener la celda correspondiente deberás de hacer lo siguiente:

```
func capturarPantalla(sender: UIButton) {

    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) else {
        return
    }

    // En este punto ya tienes que "cell" es del tipo UITableViewCell
    // y puedes hacer lo que necesites con dicha celda

}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Tengo esto para recoger el boton, `let btnCaptura: UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UIButton` `btnCaptura.tag = indexPath.row` pero me da error: `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` @mhergon

Comment: Ese error te lo da para el botón? Si es que si, el problema es que no hay ningún botón con el `tag` igual a 20 en la celda.

Comment: Si, si lo hay lo he revisado varias veces. Pero si comento la linea del tag: `btnCaptura.tag = indexPath.row` funciona bien y no me da error @mhergon

Comment: Haz un `print(btnCaptura)` justo antes de asignar el `tag` para asegurarte que no sea `nil`

Comment: me da error cuando asigno el boton, por lo que no llega al print, pero el error no lo hace en todas las celdas, solo en lagunas @mhergon

Comment: No será el error porque al leer el boton: `let btnCaptura: UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(99) as! UIButton`  ya tiene un tag y al asignarle otro da error?? El print de los botones es este: `<UIButton: 0x12f1a0140; frame = (148 224; 29 29); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 99; layer = <CALayer: 0x12f1e6df0>>` @mhergon

Comment: No puede ser que de error al asignar el tag entonces... muy raro sería...

Comment: He añaido el error del debug a mi pregunta @mhergon